# Problem with displaying equation with a colorful background with Xaringan

Tags: r, r-markdown, xaringan

When using Bookdown (HTML output), the following works perfectly:

```
$$\require{color}\displaystyle{\colorbox{#FFD1DC}{
$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \ldots + \beta_n X_n.$}}$$
```

However, with Xaringan, the equation is not even rendered.

Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$$\require{color}\displaystyle 
\colorbox{#FFD1DC}{$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \ldots + \beta_n X_n$}$$
```

or same:

```
$$\require{color}\displaystyle\colorbox{#FFD1DC}{$Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 X_1 + \ldots + \beta_n X_n$}$$
```

**To the future:** Be careful with whitespaces. Xarigan is so overnice with them.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, @manro, once again! It almost works perfectly: a backtick is put on the left of the rendered equation! Where does such a backtick come from?!

Comment: @PaulSmith Add one whitespace before the first ```$$```

Comment: Yeah, @manro, that did the trick! Thank you very much indeed for your help!

Comment: @PaulSmith Good luck in the New year ;)

Comment: Happy New Year for you too, @manro!